# What to do with the inconvenient tab suggestions of Matlab

Tags: matlab, tabs

Why doesn't Matlab put your variable's names on the top of it's suggestion like Eclipse. It's not smart to put everything in alphabetical order. Scrolling down to the function/variable you are looking for sometimes takes more time than typing it yourself. Besides it should also complete a function by writing the parenthesis and placing the courser in the middle of the parenthesis. Is there any way I can change the preferences to that it would act like Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

In short: No.

Matlab is not eclipse and it will never be. M-code is not Java code.

If you want to you can use eclipse to edit your m-files, however it will not behave as you describe in your question. This is because m-code is not as strict as for example Java, this is on one side the downside of Matlab as you describe above, however the positive side of this is that it offers flexibility during development.

Using a tab after typing some characters would narrow the possibilities for auto-fill, if you have selected this property in the Preferences-Keyboard window.